# How can i convert sql query to lambda in java?

Tags: java, sql, lambda, java-8

I have a sql query. I could not convert this query to lambda. Can you help me for convert this query to lambda?

I have a `List<Evaluator>`. I want to get the average of the answer.value from this list. Group By evaluator.relationship and question.groupName

Sql query:

```
SELECT v.relationship, q.group_name, q.order_number, avg(a.value)  from evaluation e
LEFT JOIN evaluator v on e.id = v.evaluation
LEFT JOIN answer a on v.id = a.evaluator
LEFT JOIN question q ON a.question = q.id
where e.id='b19e8a34-d786-11e6-89b9-38b1dbfd82dd'
GROUP BY v.relationship, q.group_name, q.order_number
ORDER BY v.relationship, q.order_number;
```

Entity Diagrams:

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of this transformation? I do hope you don't plan to let the client application perform the work that could be done much more efficiently in the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
evaluators.stream()
    .flatMap(evaluator -> evaluator.getAnswers().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        answer -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(answer.getEvaluator().getRelationship(), 
                                                answer.getQuestion().getGroupName()),
        Collectors.averagingInt(Answer::getValue)));
```

---

Explanation :

- Stream your evaluators.
- For each evaluator, flatmap it answers stream so that you now have a `Stream<Answer>`.
- Collect your answers using [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) with a group mapper, and a reduction for the value.
- For the group mapper, create a pair (using [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html)) of `answer.evaluator.relationship` and `answer.question.groupName`.
- For the reduction, use [Collectors.averagingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to average all values in the current group. Note that this will return a `Double`.

So you should end up with a `Map<Entry, Double>`. You could also create a `String` for the key instead of `Map.Entry` if you prefer, but that may result in a lot of unnecessary string concatenations.